# Woocommerce product import through CSV ? Does it call product updated hook?

Tags: woocommerce, import, product

Does the Woocommerce product update hook is called when products are uploaded/updated using CSV ?

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it myself. the hook gets called every time CSV is uploaded